# IllegalMonitorStateException - Attempt to unlock read lock, not locked by current thread, but I don't know why

Tags: java, redis, redisson

```
        RLock lock = lockService.getLock(TOPICNAME_LOCK_PREFIX + topicPrefix);
        if (lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            try {
                // Process business CODE

            } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new ServiceException(String.format("error: %s！", e));
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        // No lock obtained CODE
```

lockService code：

```
    private static RedissonClient redissonClient;

    private static synchronized void initClient(String url) {
        if (redissonClient == null) {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(url);
                Config config = new Config();
                SingleServerConfig srvConfig = config.useSingleServer().
                setAddress(String.format("%s://%s:%s", uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()));
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(uri.getUserInfo())) {
                    srvConfig.setPassword(uri.getUserInfo());
                }
                config.setLockWatchdogTimeout(10000);
                redissonClient = Redisson.create(config);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(String.format("cannot init redisson client by %s", url), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        initClient(redisProperties.getUrl());
    }


    public RLock getLock(String key) {
        initClient(redisProperties.getUrl());
        return redissonClient.getLock(key);
    }
```

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exceptions **sometimes** occur：

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: attempt to unlock lock, not
> locked by current thread by node id: 1118*e65ad1 thread-id: 85*45     at
> org.redisson.RedissonBaseLock.lambda$unlockAsync$2(RedissonBaseLock.java:328)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
> at
> org.redisson.command.CommandBatchService.lambda$executeAsync$7(CommandBatchService.java:322)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
> at
> org.redisson.command.RedisCommonBatchExecutor.handleResult(RedisCommonBatchExecutor.java:163)
> at
> org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor.checkAttemptPromise(RedisExecutor.java:524)
> at
> org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor.lambda$execute$4(RedisExecutor.java:176)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
> at
> org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommandBatch(CommandDecoder.java:318)
> at
> org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:210)
> at
> org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:137)
> at
> org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:113)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:882)

The business logic is that only one task is allowed in a certain range, so it needs to acquire the lock first, and other tasks are waiting. If it does not obtain the lock after waiting for 5 seconds, another set of logic will be executed.

This set of code has almost no errors, because lock.unlock() is only executed if lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) returns true.

However, for certain business peak hours, the above exceptions sometimes occur. The specific performance is that many tasks report errors: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: attempt to unlock, not locked by current thread by node id: SameId thread id: DifferentThreadId.The above error reports occur in a centralized manner. Many threads release the same lock within a few seconds.

Is this caused by network? Or is there a problem with the code?

---

I solved this problem by using Semaphore
（org.redisson.api.RPermitExpirableSemaphore）

Comment: Hard to see how that wouldn't be a bug in Redisson

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be because the lock acquired by thread A, but the implementation of thread B tried to unlock it.
The solution is to judge whether the thread is the current thread and whether the lock is locked by the thread when unlocking.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hi8S.png)
you can try.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, logs, errors, or other text.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check if the lock is held by current thread before unlocking.

```
 finally {
        if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```